# $ \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{k-1} - \frac{1}{k} \right) = 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'm reading a proof and very rusty. I'm missing something simple I suspect.

Have a little mercy and give me a nudge in the right direction?

$2\epsilon + \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} 2\epsilon \left( \frac{1}{k-1} - \frac{1}{k} \right) = 4\epsilon$

I can use $\sum k^{-2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ to show that it is less than $6\epsilon$ which also works for the proof this is from, but how do I show it is exactly $4\epsilon$ since that is how the book does it? In other words how do I show:

$ \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{k-1} - \frac{1}{k} \right) = 1$

I would prefer a hint.

Comment: Take the partial sums and see what's getting canceled ...

Comment: So (if you're very rusty): $\frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} +  \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4}... + \frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{1}{n}$ e.g. equals $1 - \frac{1}{n}.$

Comment: what a ridicolous downvote

Comment: @Obriareos Your comment is effectively the answer I posted.

Comment: @ tired: Downvote? 
@ Dr. MV: that's true - I haven't see your answer before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2}^K\left(\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac1k\right)&=\left(1-\frac12\right)+\left(\frac12-\frac13\right)+\left(\frac13-\frac14\right)+\cdots +\left(\frac{1}{K-1}-\frac{1}{K}\right)\\\\
&=1-\frac1K \tag 1
\end{align}$$

More formally, note that if $S_K=\sum_{k=2}^K\left(\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac1k\right)$, then $S_{K+1}=S_K+\frac{1}{K}-\frac{1}{K+1}$.  So, we can use induction to prove the result given by $(1)$.

Comment: Hehe ...too many very similar to a basic question. I'm deleting mine...+1

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes indeed.

Answer (score 17):

Hint:

[image]

hope you can take it from here.

As @CarstenS pointed out the picture [shown here](http://www.invitinghome.com/telescopes-binoculars/img/telescope-023-1.jpg) is somehow a more correct hint

Comment: Telescoping series

Comment: Now that deserves a (+1) just for the creativity!

Comment: @Oliver821 very good!

Comment: @Dr.MV thank you very much! :)

Comment: Yes the hint should be obvious by now. Hint: Split the sums and solve each telescoping series individually.

Comment: @tired thanks!!

Comment: Good answer ! (+1)

Comment: And this put a big smile on my face.  Nice picture by the way.

Comment: @Dr.MV the humorless guys are never far... what a poor downvote

Comment: Better image (I did not check the rights, though): http://www.invitinghome.com/telescopes-binoculars/img/telescope-023-1.jpg Your telescope does not telescope!

Comment: @CarstenS haha you are right...it was just one of the first pictures i saw when i entered "telescope" into google

Comment: @tired +1, and here is yet another safe-to-use [telescoping cylinder](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:8-stage_single-acting_air_cylinder,_Ergo-Help.jpg).

Comment: Now we need a picture to represent a series.  Maybe a large $\Sigma$ would suffice.

Comment: @Dr. MV: How about that one: http://combiboilersleeds.com/images/series/series-3.jpg

Comment: That should do it.  Hilarious

Answer (score 1):

It's a [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

First show:

$$\sum_{k=2}^N \frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}=1-\frac{1}{N}$$

Answer (score 1):

Fix $n\geq 2$. Then $$\sum_{k=2}^n\left(\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}\right)=\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k-1}-\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}=1+\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{n}=1-\frac{1}{n}.$$
Let $n\to \infty $ and you'll get your result.

Answer (score 1):

Well it has been done before, but I still like to give another method:

$$\sum_{k=2}^{m}\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{1}{k}+1$$$$=\left[\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\frac{1}{k}-\ln\left(m-1\right)\right]-\left[\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{1}{k}-\ln\left(m\right)\right]+1+\ln\left(\frac{m-1}{m}\right)$$

Taking the limit of the expression yields:

$$\underbrace{\left[\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\frac{1}{k}-\ln\left(m-1\right)\right]}_{\gamma }-\underbrace{\left[\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{1}{k}-\ln\left(m\right)\right]}_{\gamma }+1+0=\color{red}{1}$$

Where $\gamma$ is [Euler–Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).